# Periodically process data using aws emr

Tags: amazon-emr, emr

I think I have a similar question to the one asked in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838652/amazon-mapreduce-best-practices-for-logs-analysis), but I will try to be more specific...

What is the best way to periodically process data using aws. For example, I want to process some reports I aggregated into S3 once per minute. Is the best way to do it to add a step to an existing job every minute via some script?

Answer (score 2):

Well, for now I will write a script that:

- Gets the job flow details from aws
- If the job is in status waiting - add a new step to the job
- Since I am using aws PHP AmazonEMR, I will add some code to handle
  the 256 max steps limitation (create new job flow with the same
  parameters and terminate the existing one if I have more than 200
  steps, for example).

I'll update this thread once I have the code ready and later on once I see how it holds in production for a few weeks

Comment: How did it go in production? I see it's been years. Just asking. :)

Comment: @siliconsenthil - I'm sure these days there are much better solutions (like lambada), but this script has been running since 2012 in production. Works well with little maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a bootstrap action to install a cron job on the master node.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the (new) AWS Lambda service. You upload your script and set a S3 bucket/folder to monitor. The code is run every time new input is added to the folder, and spins up EC2 instances as necessary to keep up with demand.

https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/